# select users, then sum and count that user

Tags: mysql, sql, count, union

I have these two query, the first I look for the users, who have transactions in the last two months the second I sum and tell these users, but with all transactions of all time, the question is how do to assemble this query, first I look and then sum and tell?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_ju1) from master where fecha_registro > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)

SELECT sum(precio)  / count(DISTINCT(id_ju1)) AS TOTAL FROM master
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Also table definition would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one query:

```
SELECT sum(m.precio)  / count(DISTINCT(m.id_ju1)) AS TOTAL FROM master m 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master m1 WHERE m1.fecha_registro > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) 
AND m.id_ju1=m1.id_ju1)
```